# Speed up correlated query with UPDATE and COUNT

Tags: sql, db2

I have scheme With `Users`, `Reviews`, and Many to Many relation between, which decide who rated which review as `Helpful`. Over time helpful table grows into having about 10 milion rows so I decided to cache `Count()` result in `Reviews` table. So I can easily tell user how many times certain review got rated. Problem is that when I do it using following correlated query it takes ages.

```
UPDATE EXT.REVIEWS AS R 
SET HELPFUL_COUNTER = 
    (SELECT COUNT (*) 
    FROM EXT.USERS_REVIEWS_HELPFUL AS H 
    WHERE R.PK = H.REVIEW_FK)
```

Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: The problem is you are executing the 'COUNT(*)` over and over again. Try pushing the subquery into a temporary table and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to speed up such a query is to use an index.  In this case, the appropriate index is `USERS_REVIEWS_HELPFUL(REVIEW_FK)`.

Comment: Uhh it executed like in 5 seconds, much tank you.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have any db2 credentials but the two normal ways of overcoming a dynamic calculation is either: 1) a materialised view where these values are precalculated prior to you accessing them, 2) manipulating the number as you go (but this requires maintenance code to keep it in sync and can get messy). Personally I would look at (1) and then add an index to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MERGE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-6-154&lang=en)

```
MERGE INTO EXT.REVIEWS AS R
    USING (SELECT REVIEW_FK, 
                  Count(*) Counter
             FROM EXT.USERS_REVIEWS_HELPFUL
            GROUP BY REVIEW_FK) AS H
    ON (R.PK = H.REVIEW_FK)
    WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET HELPFUL_COUNTER = H.Counter;
```

And make sure that there are no triggers on update in `EXT.REVIEWS`.

Also it's possible to make a separate table `(PK,Counter)` and not update `EXT.REVIEWS` but insert result of select into this separate table:

```
             INSERT INTO EXT.REV_COUNTER (PK,Counter)
              SELECT REVIEW_FK, 
                  Count(*) Counter
             FROM EXT.USERS_REVIEWS_HELPFUL
            GROUP BY REVIEW_FK
```

Answer (score 0):

For readers whose DB2 server is running under **IBM i** OS, you may consider using an EVI.

```
CREATE ENCODED VECTOR INDEX  EXT.USERS_REVIEWS_HELPFUL_EV1
  on EXT.USERS_REVIEWS_HELPFUL (REVIEW_FK)
  INCLUDE ( count(*) )
```

I would do this in addition to creating a "normal" index, known as a radix index, as recommended by Gordon.

When running your query, the system need only probe (ie. read) a single index entry for each REVIEW_FK value, dramatically improving performance of querying the `count(*)`.  The maintenance cost of this index is so minimal, especially compared to index maintenance on other platforms, that it should generally not be a concern, unless INSERT performance is already pressing against acceptable limits.

Sadly, DB2 for LUW or z/OS do not (yet?) support this type of index.